# React - A More Comprehensive Email Validation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, email-validation

I'm looking to do a more comprehensive email validation than the one I currently have. If you take a look at my code, I'm only checking for @ symbol and ends in .com. Is there a more comprehensive validation check I can include into my current code configuration?

JS:

```
this.state = {
  inputs: {
    name: '',
    email: '',
    message: '',
  },
  errors: {
    name: false,
    email: false,
    message: false,
  },
};

handleOnChange = e => {

const { name, value } = e.target;

if (name === 'email') {
  this.setState({
    inputs: {
      ...this.state.inputs,
      [name]: value,
    },
    errors: {
      ...this.state.errors,
      email:
        (value.includes('@') && value.slice(-4).includes('.com'))
          ? false
          : true,
    },
  });
} else {
  this.setState({
    inputs: {
      ...this.state.inputs,
      [name]: value,
    },
    errors: {
      ...this.state.errors,
      [name]: false,
    },
  });
}
```

};

Comment: You should consider using regex so simplify your validation. Check the link in the comment above

Comment: Whatever answers you get (or not) you ought to read this: https://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

Comment: Also, Eric, what about the `.net` , `.edu` , and `.us` email addresses I have? They are valid but will fail your test for `.com`

Comment: ...finally... why don't you just use a `<input type="email" ...>`?

Comment: Thanks all - the regex solution will work perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

The best way to validate email is using regular expressions:

```
const emailRegEx = /^(([^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]{2,})$/i;
```

The above will match 99.99% of valid emails

Comment: The "official" RFC 5322 regex (the one you show in your answer?) is listed at https://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html (great read) and at  https://emailregex.com/#container among other places.

Comment: Thanks for the source